# raw CIFilter has nil outputImage

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter, dng

I get some DNG raw files and want to show them in iPhone. I use `CIFilter` to read the raw file, but when I try to get the `outputImage`, it returns `nil`.
The code looks like:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"1" withExtension:@"DNG"];
CIFilter *filter = nil;
filter = [CIFilter filterWithImageURL:url options:nil];
[filter setValue:@(2000) forKey:kCIInputNeutralTemperatureKey];
CIImage *imgCI = [filter.outputImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIVignette"];//5
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:imgCI];
```

In the line 5, the `fileter.outputImage` is nil and hence the final `img` is nil. I check the DNG file in Mac and it shows it is `Adobe Raw`. I also print the `filter` in console:

> CIRAWFilterImpl: inputRequestedSushiMode=nil inputNeutralChromaticityX=0.5342335533653005 inputNeutralChromaticityY=0.4233451399853654 inputNeutralTemperature=2000 inputNeutralTint=9.616524016108169 inputNeutralLocation=[] inputEV=0 inputBoost=1 inputDraftMode=nil inputScaleFactor=1 inputIgnoreOrientation=nil inputImageOrientation=1 inputEnableSharpening=1 inputEnableNoiseTracking=1 inputEnableVendorLensCorrection=0 inputNoiseReductionAmount=0 inputLuminanceNoiseReductionAmount=nil inputColorNoiseReductionAmount=nil inputNoiseReductionSharpnessAmount=nil inputNoiseReductionContrastAmount=nil inputNoiseReductionDetailAmount=nil inputMoireAmount=nil inputDecoderVersion=nil inputBoostShadowAmount=nil inputBias=nil inputBaselineExposure=nil inputDisableGamutMap=0 inputHueMagMR=nil inputHueMagRY=nil inputHueMagYG=nil inputHueMagGC=nil inputHueMagCB=nil inputHueMagBM=nil inputLinearSpaceFilter=nil>

The `inputDecoderVersion` seems nil which may cause the problem(but I'm not sure).
The DNG files are downloaded from Internet, and I also try the `NEF` files which has the same result.

Could anyone give some advice?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but have you tried your code against a "true" RAW image (not a proprietary one that can be converted to RAW)?

Answer (score 2):

It should run in real device.
In simulator, it returns `nil`.

Comment: Man, they should definitely add some big notes in the documentation about that